# Android Open GL ES texture problems

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am having a problem that I think is possibly to do with texture coordinates, the image below shows my tile map being rendered - however sometimes there are gaps appearing between the tiles as can be seen in the screenshot at the following url (Half way down the screen there is a gap between tiles).

http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/4724/tileproblem.png

My texture regions are declared as

```
public class TextureRegion {    
public final float u1, v1;
public final float u2, v2;
public final Texture texture;

public TextureRegion(Texture texture, float x, float y, float width, float height) {
    this.u1 = x / texture.width;
    this.v1 = y / texture.height;
    this.u2 = this.u1 + width / texture.width;
    this.v2 = this.v1 + height / texture.height;        
    this.texture = texture;
    }
}
```

The tile textures come from an atlas and are 32x32 pixels, I am using GL_Nearest

being new to Open GL, I do not quite understand what I need to change.

Example of texture creation

```
tile = new TextureRegion(items, 192,160,34,34);
```

Cheers

Stuart

Comment: Sure this is a tex coords problem? Looks more like a geometric one. Even when there's something wrong with the tex coords, the background _shouldn't_ be visible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stefan, I think I agree with you, I am currently revisiting my polygon generation code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your texture are base 2, for example 128x256 or 512x512 etc.